# Set cookie from SignalR hub on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Is there anyway I can set a cookie from inside a SignalR hub, specifically the `OnConnected` method. I want to send a cookie with a session id.

I tried this but it didn't seem to work, it also looks awkward because I'm not sure why I need to provide a key value pair of a string and a cookie.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var guid = new Guid();
    Context.RequestCookies.Add("SessionID", new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie("SessionID", guid.ToString()));
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles on it, there's a way to add cookies from a hub in signalr 2.0+. The HttpContextBase can be accessed through hub request context, so you can do something like this:

```
var newCookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue");
Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
```

Comment: It's not working and says "Response is not available in this context."

Answer (score 3):

I eventually decided to set the cookie from the serving MVC controller, i did not find anyway to set this from in a SignalR call.

Answer (score 1):

Signal-R is a communication channel. It will try to assume the best possible speed/technology, but downgrade nicely until it ends up with a long-poll http request.

The current most optimal network connection is established using Websockets, but you cannot depend on that 100%

Notice that each and every Signal-R connection established ALSO generates a UNIQUE URL as parameter for the connection request. This parameter is the "connection Id", and if you refresh your browser, it will generate a new one.

So, if you use a cookie as a "session identifier" so you can keep a session even if the user decides to refresh the browser, be aware that the cookie value is also shared among ALL the browser tabs open on that device.

You cannot write the Cookie from the response of the Hub, but you can write a Cookie using  eg. Razor/MVC controllers or pure javascript... BEFORE you open the Signal-R connection - and THEN you can read that Cookie value from the `Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Cookies` collection.

BUT READ-ONLY !

The point is, make "login systems" on normal Razor pages or whatever means you have, and then write the cookies you need - and THEN open the Signal-R connection and utilize that session for whatever purpose you might have.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to subclass and use PersistentConnection instead of Hub to have more options on the server.

In my case I override OnConnectedAsync and use the connectionId in there to keep track of connections/sessions. Maybe you can consider this approach?

```
protected override Task OnConnectedAsync(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
```

Comment: i can't really switch from PersistentConnections to hubs, that's kind of a radical change

Answer (score -3):

I just tried the same thing and this seems to work:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: The talk is about SignalR, but not MVC.

Comment: Long time ago, but pretty sure I did it in a SignalR context.

Comment: Update your answer with a correction and I will unminus.

Comment: This just throws `Response is not available in this context` for me