# Append Cookie - SignalR Core

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Inside a **Hub** when I try to add a cookie I get this error: *"The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started"*.

Here is a sample code of adding a cookie inside a Hub:

```
if (!Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("_a_cookie")) {
    Context.GetHttpContext().Response.Cookies.Append("_a_cookie", "1");
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Could you pls tell us your goal for adding cookie? If you only need to save some data, you may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15506584).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up implementing my own middleware that adds the cookie like this when a client tries to connect:

```
public class SignalRCookieIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SignalRCookieIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) {
        if(context.Request.Path == "/{HUB_NAME}/negotiate") {
            if (!context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("_a_cookie")) {
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("_a_cookie", 1);
            }
        }
        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

and then inside **Configure** of **Startup.cs** I added:

```
app.UseMiddleware<SignalRCookieIdMiddleware>();
```

Answer (score 0):

[SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0#signalr) is based on WebSockets, and we know that websocket is different from http, but cookie is supported by http but not websocket till now.

So the only chance to set cookie in signalr hub is at the time the connection is connected, because that connect request in based on http.